# how to count elements in each column of a table in R

Tags: r, count, missing-data

i have a data set which look like this (actually it has >50 columns)

`data <- read.csv("sample.csv")`

```
subject gender  age type    satisfation     agree 
1   f   22  a   yes yes
2   f   23  b   no  yes 
3   f   21  b       no
4   m   24  c   yes yes 
5   f   22  b   no  yes
6   m       a   yes yes 
7       25  c   yes no
8   m   21  b   no  yes 
9   f   23  c   yes yes
```

I would like to count the elements in each column (don't count NA) and export the result as the layout below

```
subject gender  age type    satisfation     agree 
9   8   8   9   8   9
```

i wrote a script to count

```
counting <- function(x) {
  for(i in 1:length(data)) {
     data <- length(which(!is.na(x$i)))
      print(data)
  }
  return(data)
}   
counting(data)
```

i didn't work out as it gave all 0.

`dput(head(data, 9))`

```
structure(list(subject = 1:9, gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("", "f", "m"), class = "factor"), 
    age = c(22L, 23L, 21L, 24L, 22L, NA, 25L, 21L, 23L), type = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"
    ), class = "factor"), satisfation = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("", "no", "yes"), class = "factor"), 
    agree = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("no", 
    "yes", "yes "), class = "factor"), time = c(23L, 54L, 67L, 
    324L, 87L, 12L, 756L, 34L, 98L), day = c(1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
    7L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L)), .Names = c("subject", "gender", "age", 
"type", "satisfation", "agree", "time", "day"), row.names = c(NA, 
9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is there any recommendation for the script, plz?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Type `x$i` and inspect the result... You probably want to just use `sapply` or something here or maybe just `summary` (which reports NA counts)

Comment: @Frank i'm not quite sure if i get what you mean. summary does count the NA which i dont want to count :(

Comment: I mean: Did you type `x$i` to confirm that you are not using the syntax correctly? And second, `summary` shows you the info you want, albeit not in your preferred format (which you could get from `sapply`). If you haven't even read the data in from csv yet, maybe you aren't ready to attempt this problem; but if you have, you can type `dput(DF)` and copy the result here as Richard said...

Comment: Copy the output of `dput(head(data, 9))` in the question.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns i did

Comment: Try doing `data <- read.csv("sample.csv", na.strings = "")` followed by `sapply(data, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))`.

Comment: You need `strip.white = TRUE` in your `read.csv()` call as well.  This will allow `na.strings = ""` to get it right.  Plus you have extra space in the other columns too.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you have handled `NA` then simply use `colSums`,

```
colSums(!is.na(df))
#    subject    gender       age       type   satisfation    agree      time        day 
#          9      9           8           9           9       9          9           9
```

Adding @DavidArenburg suggestion so as to overcome any `NA` trouble,

```
colSums(!is.na(df) | df != "", na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Problem with this is that there seem to be NAs that aren't coded for in the data.  So just using this alone wouldn't be accurate.

Comment: yes, so as you said in your answer "After you get the NAs, you can run this code. Assume your table is called `df`.", right?

Comment: Right!  I just thought that your answer in a vacuum is incomplete.  In context it makes sense.  Maybe update it with the caveat that's mentioned by myself and others?

Answer (score 5):

When I load your table into R there are just blank spaces instead of NAs.  So when you read your .csv file, specify how NAs are coded.  It looks like they are coded as "" or maybe " ".

After you get the NAs, you can run this code.  Assume your table is called `df`.

```
counts <- apply(df, 2, function(x) length(na.omit(x)))
```

Or, as @JasonAizkalns suggests:

```
data <- read.csv("sample.csv", na.strings = "") 
sapply(data, function(x) sum(!is.na(x))
```

Comment: If you dont mind can ask i how do I write an additional code to add these counts together? I mean to count elements in the whole table (omit NA)

Comment: If you want the total number of elements in the whole table, try calling `sum(counts)`.  :)

Comment: i did `sum(counts)` and i also tried `sum(!is.na(data))`. it gave me 2 different number. Do you know why?

Comment: Is `data` a data frame/table?  If it is giving you the sum of all integers in your table that is going to be a different number than giving you the sum of how many integers are in your table.

Comment: it is a table with string, interger,... i would like to count all elements (data points) in the table. which code should i use?

Comment: oh it also has data and time format and i would like to count all of them

Comment: So then you want to use `sum(counts)`.  `counts` already represents the number of elements in each column.  If you add those all up, you have the number of elements in the table.

Comment: the `apply` solution is awful - it converts the data to a matrix first

Comment: @eddi so in your opinion i should use `sapply` ?

Comment: @PNY sure, or the other answer, but not `apply`